# Reversing the IP address in Linux using perl

Tags: perl

I have a job where I need to do nslookup on an IP address. If it matches then I need to print the name of the host. The problem is that the IP address comes reversed when running the command.

```
nslookup 10.11.12.13
13.12.11.10.in-addr.arpa
```

I tried to use `reverse` but that reversed everything which is not what I want.

```
my $ip = '13.12.11.10';
$result = reverse($ip);
print $result;
```

which then prints `01.11.21.31`
I do not want to reverse everything, just the full numbers.

Please can someone help?

Comment: just split the reversed IP address and reorder them.

Comment: `$result = join ".", reverse split /[.]/, $ip`

Comment: I'm curious, why are you doing this?  What's an example of an nslookup result that doesn't match?

Comment: @ysth There a whole bunch of old lookup entries that are pointing to the incorrect ip's, so instead of doing them one by one, I use the script and input all the ip's to see where the incorrect entries are. So as example, there are servers that has the correct IP and hostname, but their lookup entries are incorrect.

Comment: Re "*If it matches*", It always will. `nslookup 10.11.12.13` is a shortcut for `nslookup -type=ptr 13.12.11.10.in-addr.arpa`

Comment: @ikegami yes, but if it a servername is registered as `10.11.12.14` and I do a lookup for `10.11.12.13`  I will not get a result back, and that is how I am testing.

Comment: That's not what you asked, though, and that doesn't require reversing Anything! You just need to check if you got a result back; you don't also have to check if the query is your query because it will always be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what we need to do is to just split the actual address, reorder them in reverse and then match the IP to the reversed IP.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ipaddress = '10.11.12.13';    
my @ip = split /\./,$ipaddress;                      #split the IP by .
my $sserddapi = "$ip[3].$ip[2].$ip[1].$ip[0]";       #reverse it
my @lookup = `nslookup $ipaddress`;                  #do the match
   $lookup[3] =~ s/\s+//g;                           #remove all whitespace
my @device = split /=/, $lookup[3];                  #get the hostname
    if ($lookup[3] =~ /^$sserddapi/) {               #see if it matches
    $lookup[3] =~ s/$sserddapi.in-addr.arpaname=//g; #Remove the unwanted stuff
    print "$ipaddress = $lookup[3]\n";               #print the result
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: Where you interpolate `$sserddapi` in regexes, you want `\Q$sserddapi\E` instead.  And you want \ before the .'s in your substitution.  Also, your if match for 13.12.11.10 would match e.g. 13.12.11.101 too, which I'm guessing is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Simply split the IP address on `.`s using `split`, reverse the resulting array, then rejoin it:

```
join(".", reverse(split(/\./, $ip)))
```

This will give you the "reversed" IP address, which you can then compare to the `nslookup` result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I marked the other one as correct it gave me the match as well but this one is good. it says I cannot vote as I do not have 15 reputation yet so cannot vote your answer up.